# How can i restrict the textbox value to stay same in the access database

Tags: vba, ms-access

My goal is to create an access database form with ordering multiple item at a time. But for this phase my end goal is to find the total cost by multiplying price per unit*quantity. Through my working out i got stucked by the problem of on change event. Basically, whenever i change a the id in the combo box it changes in all the textbox that i programmed. 
Here is the scenario: 
[image]

In this case the price per unit stays 1000 for all of the stock ID, whereas, when i have stock id of 2 i want the price to be 0 and so on. 
[image]
This is how i programmed the get price per unit value

```
Private Sub StockIDCombo_Change()
Me.PricePerUnit.Value = Me.StockIDCombo.Column(3)
End Sub
```

Note that the form is continuous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have an additional field in the table to hold the calculation, and bind your textbox to this field.

Answer (score 0):

Is your PricePerUnit control unbound? It should be bounded to some table field as other fields (StockID, Quantity).